# Scaling Kafka streams application using kubernetes horizontal pod scaling

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka-streams, kubernetes-pod

We have a kafka streams application with 3 pods. Application scaling is a heavy operation(because of large state) for us.  So, I would like to increase/scale pod only if it absolutely necessary. For example, if the application utilization increases beyond a number for lets say 10 mins.

Again, i don't need to scale up/down my application for sudden burst(a fews seconds) of messages

Looking for something configuration like:
window : 15 mins
avergae cpu : 1000 milli

So, I would like to scale the application is the average cpu over 15 mins window is greater than 1000 milli.

Comment: Just wondering if you read the docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/ as it explains a few approaches to autoscaling with very similar examples to what you want to do. And please test this thoroughly. Kafka doesn't like re-balancing. It's a lot better now, but it's still an easy way to bring down any platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into [HPA policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#scaling-policies).

There is [`stabilizationWindowSeconds`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#stabilization-window):

> StabilizationWindowSeconds is the number of seconds for which past
> recommendations should be considered while scaling up or scaling down.
> StabilizationWindowSeconds must be greater than or equal to zero and
> less than or equal to 3600 (one hour). If not set, use the default
> values: - For scale up: 0 (i.e. no stabilization is done)

And the limits CPU average utilization can be set in [metric target objects](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#resourcemetricsource-v2beta2-autoscaling) under `averageUtilization`.

Comment: This is only for ScaleDown. I think it doesn't work for Scaleup